# pip in path but command not found

Tags: linux, raspbian, octoprint

I'm running a fresh installed OctoPi image (0.18.0). I added pip to my PATH in .bashrc file and sourced it but when I try to run pip I'm getting `-bash: pip: command not found` error.

When I run `/home/pi/oprint/bin/pip`, pip is working properly.

My path:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/oprint/bin/pip:
```

Comment: Is `: No such file or directory` part of `$PATH`? If yes, then shorten your `$PATH` to `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/oprint/bin/pip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the full path of the executable to the path, but you're only supposed to add the directory of the executable. Every exectuable of said directory is then directly available without the directory prefix.

In other words .. instead of `/home/pi/oprint/bin/pip` you should add `/home/pi/oprint/bin/` to the path.

Comment: thanks that was it, I was convince that specifing the file was possible instead of including all the directory

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend using the Python executable to locate the `pip` executable for you. This way, you know the right version of `pip` is being used to install packages that are compliant with your Python version.

```
$ python -m pip install <the_package_you_want>
```

It is really easy to end up with mismatched versions otherwise!

Comment: I get `/usr/bin/python3: no module named pip`, any way to change the configured pip directory?

Comment: Please post the exact output of `$ echo $PATH` in your answer, using a [code block](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks), and comment here when you are done. If you do that, then I can help you further